# Hadoop: Cost of reading non-local data from other Datanodes

Tags: hadoop

By default, Hadoop splits the files to be processed by a Mapper on the file's block boundaries. That is, that's what the FileInputFormat implementation does for getSplits(). Hadoop then makes sure that the blocks to be processed by a Mapper are replicated on the Datanode the Mapper runs on.

Now I'm wondering, if I need to read outside of this InputSplit (in a RecordReader, but that's irrelevant), what does this cost me as opposed to reading inside the InputSplit - Assuming that the data outside of it is not present on the reading Datanode?

**EDIT:**

In other words:
**I am a RecordReader** and have been assigned an **InputSplit that spans one file block**. I have a local copy of this file block (rather, the datanode I'm running on does), but not the rest of the file. Now I **do need to read outside of this InputSplit**, because I need to read the **file header** which is at the very beginning. Then I need to skip across records in the file (by reading just the records headers which tells me how long each record is and than skipping that amount of bytes). I need to do this until I encounter the first record that's inside the InputSplit. Then I can start reading the actual records within my InputSplit. That is the only way to make sure that I will start at a valid record boundary.

**Question**: When I do read outside of the InputSplit, when is the data from the non-local file blocks copied? Is this done one byte at a time (i.e. once per call of InputStream.read()), or is the entire file block (of the current InputStream position) copied to my local datanode once I call InputStream.read() until I encounter the next non-local file block, etc? I need to know this so I can estimate how much overhead will be produced by skipping through the file.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In best of my understanding if data is not resided on local datanode - it will not be involved in reading it. HDFS client will ask NameNode where blocks are sitting and will directly speak with relevant datanodes in order to get the blocks. 
So cost will be - on remote datanode : read from disk, calculate CRC, send to the network, on code reading data - get from the network. 
I think cluster-wise price is only network bandwidth and some CPU spent on sending, receiving.

Comment: Thanks for your response! This partyly answered my question, but I'm rather interested in how much data is copied at a time, so I can estimate how much overhead will be produced by reading just a few bytes in a non-local file location.

Comment: I think overhead is small and taking into account size of Ethernet frames - I would consider overhead close to zero. Main overhead will be HDFS layers - it is not optimized for small reads.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that, assuming a mapper job runs around an hour for a large scale task, this overhead is indeed close to zero and can be ignored. In that sense, data locality probably only needs to be worried about in an environment where the cluster is distributed across different datacenters with a low bandwidth connection *and* the size of the FileSplits (or file blocks) is chosen to be rather small, which the default being 64 MB blocks, usually isn't the case either.

Answer (score 0):

Data movement normally happens under two scenarios. First, if the size of InputSplit is greater than the block size. Second, if the node, that holds the block doesn't have any free slots to start a TaskTracker. In this case the block will be moved to another node which has free slots(preferably within the same rack).

Comment: Thanks for your response! Actually, my scenario is somewhat a third scenario as I implement my own InputFormat which always needs to read parts of the file that are not within the InputSplit.